# Sort by dynamic value in Amazon Dynamodb?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I understand that dynamodb uses the local secondary index as static(ex. post_date,last_post_date..)

However, Can you use dynamodb to sort by a dynamic value such as (ex. number_replies in a Thread, or number_likes in a post)?

Comment: can you explain static vs dynamic in your example?

Comment: What I mean by static is some value set once and not able to be changed. This value is usually set when doing insertion into the table such as date or name. However, I am trying to sort the entries of a table by a dynamic value that changes frequently like a counter  of some sort. Does that make sense?

Comment: to my understanding LSI is meant to work with dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit old but i thought it might help someone,

What we can do is that we can create LSI or GSI and in that we can make number_replies as range, thus when querying GSI or LSI we will fetch all the replies of particular thread in ascending or descending order.

Hope that helps